# Keep the context of this after a click event in a function object

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects, onclicklistener, dom-events

I've got an object with functions. Here's a simplified version:

```
var app = {

  functOne: function(){
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.functTwo);
  },

  functTwo: function(){
    console.log('Funct Two has Run');
    this.functThree();
  },

  functThree: function(){
        console.log('Funct Three has Run');
  }
};

app.functOne();
```

The app in `functOne` attaches a click handler to button (to launch functTwo). `FunctTwo` is supposed to execute `FunctThree` but the context of 'this' is no longer 'app' (it's now the button). How do I get 'app' again from inside (or passed to) `functTwo` (assuming app isn't just attached to window like in the above example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achieved by using [`Function.prototype.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
  functOne: function(){
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', this.functTwo.bind(this));
  },
```